# Right Outer Join avoiding duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, left-join

Can someone help for this complicated situation

I having two table

```
Table1:

id |  status     
----------------
1  |  New       
2  |  New   
3  |  Pending
```

where table2 is

Table2:

```
id  | table1_id
---------------
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 1
4   | 2
5   | 2
6   | 2
7   | 3
8   | 3
```

I am trying to extract status values, so tried with easy one

```
SELECT t1.status FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1_id
```

It giving the result

```
New 
New 
New
```

I can't able to use distinct, because I am some calculation, any idea to avoid the dupilcate here?

With the case statements I need a result like

```
 id  |  New  | Pending
 ---------------------
 1   |   1   |   0
 2   |   1   |   0
 3   |   0   |   1
```

Now getting

```
id  |  New  | Pending
 ---------------------
 1   |   3   |   0
 2   |   3   |   0
 3   |   0   |   2
```

Comment: Are you trying to just get a listing of all statuses present in Table2? It might help to understand what calculation you're doing, because if it's some sort of aggregation the solution will be different.

Comment: So you want to remove the duplicates but you can't use distinct? Can you use GROUP BY t1.status?

Comment: @Josh just assume there is one more count in table1 and 3 entries in table 3, it will give 6 outputs, but I need the count as 2

Comment: @Suganthan . . . Please give an example of the result you are looking for

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Question updated, for this i tried with case statement as well

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT t1.status` will give you the distinct values. But, since you didn't want to use `DISTINCT`, you can add `GROUP BY t1.status` it is the same as `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t1.status, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT t2.table1_id), 0) AS total
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.table1_id
GROUP BY t1.status;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c3d/7)

But this way the `GROUP BY` is a useless for only the distinct values, better use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Gamal thanks for your response, I tried with groupby as well, but while taking the count I will give 3 I need the this count as 1

Comment: @Suganthan the count of what? count of all the statuses selected? Can you please show me the full query you tried?

Comment: Yes the count of status, full query difficult, but this is the sample data explaining my problem

Comment: @Suganthan - See my edit if you want the count, [**See this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c3d/6)

Comment: thanks for effort again, but it is giving count as 3 I need 1 as count

Comment: @Suganthan - Aha, Sorry again, use `COUNT(DISTINCT t2.table1_id)` instead of just `COUNT(t2.table1_id)`. See my edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42331/discussion-between-suganthan-and-mahmoud-gamal)

Comment: But that is table_id count right, My requirement is to get status count

Comment: @Suganthan - So what is the required output for the sample data you pout in your question?

Comment: @Suganthan - Also why in the table1 there is two statuses with the same name `new`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
select id, max(t1 = 'New') as New, max(t1 = 'Pending') as Pending
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.table1_id
group by t1.id;
```

Comment: @Suganthan . . . It is equivalent to:  `max(case when t1 = 'New' then 1 else 0 end)`, but easier to write.  This is a MySQL shortcut.